# How to rename an executable from its details

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, powershell, rename

I have loads of `.exe` files that got renamed to `file1.exe`, `file2.exe`, etc. When you look at a file's Details under Properties (in Windows Explorer), it has the original file name under "Product Name".
I am trying to find a way to batch rename them all back to the product name.
There are tools that can do this with images, music, etc., but I can't find anything out there that will do it for applications. This would be (fairly) straightforward if there were some way to access the Properties → Details in a command line (batch) context.

Answer (score 5):

You can use PowerShell to do this.

```
$newname=(get-item .\file1.exe).VersionInfo.ProductName
Rename-Item .\file1.exe -NewName "$newname.exe"
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a one-liner that should accomplish what you need:

```
(gci).name | Where-Object {$_ -like 'file*.exe'} | foreach { $name=(get-item $_).versioninfo.productname;rename-item $_ -NewName "$name.exe"}
```

Answer (score 1):

to make it like ProductName_ProductVersion.exe :

```
(gci -Path "E:\test" -Filter *.exe).FullName | %{$NewName = (Get-Item $_).VersionInfo.ProductName +"_" + (Get-Item $_).VersionInfo.ProductVersion;Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$($NewName).exe"}
```

and if you want to make it like ProductName_FileVersion.exe just replace ProductVersion with FileVersion in code

DO NOT forget to replace `E:\test` with true path